# Converting C#/.NET, ruby or Python code to Delphi Indy v10

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I need to use a service of messages called pushover (https://pushover.net/) and I am trying to convert the sample code posted in other programming language to use with Delphi XE7/Indy10.

I have used the following code in Delphi and I always get: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request".

```
Procedure SendMessage;
var ...
begin 
  IdHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP.HandleRedirects:=True;
  Resp := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  sURL      :='https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json?';
  postdata := 'token=aiJSSS3167JLrPAAye9srpEz27RDJ2Rm&user=uDXXXFCASKgqLGzzuJLMdf2Ymyr5dP&message=This is a Text&title=Test'

  sFPRvalue := idhttp.URL.ParamsEncode(postdata,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  Sl:=IntToStr(length(postdata));

  s:=sURL+sFPRvalue;

  try
    SSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    try
      SSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      IdHTTP.IOHandler := SSL1;
      IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      IdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Length',sl);
      strres := IdHTTP.Post(s,Resp);
    finally
      SSl1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Resp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here are the samples posted by owner service:

C#

```cs
var parameters = new NameValueCollection {
    { "token", "APP_TOKEN" },
    { "user", "USER_KEY" },
    { "message", "hello world" }
};

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadValues("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json", parameters);
}
```

Python

```py
import http.client, urllib
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
  urllib.parse.urlencode({
    "token": "APP_TOKEN",
    "user": "USER_KEY",
    "message": "hello world",
  }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
conn.getresponse()
```

Ruby

```rb
require "net/https"

url = URI.parse("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.set_form_data({
  :token => "APP_TOKEN",
  :user => "USER_KEY",
  :message => "hello world",
})
res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
res.use_ssl = true
res.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
res.start {|http| http.request(req) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the wrong overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Post()`, and you are formatting its parameter data the wrong way.  You need to use the overloaded version of `Post()` that takes a `TStrings` as input, let it encode the post data for you, and return the response data as a `String`, eg:

```
IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
  SSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
  SSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := SSL1;

  IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

  PostData := TStringList.Create;
  try
    PostData.Add('token=aiJSSS3167JLrPAAye9srpEz27RDJ2Rm');
    PostData.Add('user=uDXXXFCASKgqLGzzuJLMdf2Ymyr5dP');
    PostData.Add('message=This is a Text');
    PostData.Add('title=Test');

    try
      strres := IdHTTP.Post('https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json', PostData);
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        if (E.ErrorCode div 100) = 4 then
        begin
          // use E.ErrorMessage as needed...
        end else begin
          raise;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    PostData.Free;
  end;
finally
  IdHTTP.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy. It works very well. How do you know the SSLOptions Method to use? And if I want to post a URL such as PostData('url=myurl'), do I have to do a url encode?

Comment: Remy, the message service help said "If any input was invalid, you will receive an HTTP 4xx status, with a JSON object or XML node containing a status code of something other than 1, and an errors array detailing which parameters were invalid.

{"user":"invalid","errors":["user identifier is invalid"],
"status":0,"request":"3c0b5952fba0ab27805159217077c177"}". When I get a HTTP 400 Errror the app aborts and I never can get this message. How could I retrieve this error message after the HTPP 400 error?

Comment: Regarding the `SSLOptions.Method` value, I read [this announcement](http://updates.pushover.net/post/100158741542/api-sslv3-support-disabled). Regarding URL-encoding a URL in the post data, I don't know for sure, but I suspect yes. You will have to try it and see what happens. Regarding the 4xx error, wrap the `Post()` in a `try/except` to catch the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception, the JSON/XML will be in its `ErrorMessage` property. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd want to give +100 to you

Comment: One question more,please, To send multiple post in a short time interval the service owner said:"To speed up multiple requests, you may send each request in sequence over the same TCP connection using HTTP keep-alive to avoid the overhead of a new TCP connection and SSL negotiation. ". How do I could do it with Indy HTTP?

Comment: I did:   IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol,hoForceEncodeParams];
  IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  IdHTTP.Request.Connection:='keep-alive';
is it ok?

Comment: `hoKeepOrigProtocol` and `Request.Connection := 'keep-alive'` are all you need for HTTP keep alives.  The `Response.KeepAlive` property will tell if the connection was actually kept alive after the response is processed.